# Is there a way to disconnect the active bluetooth device(lagacy connection) while keeping the BLE connection active with bluez?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I'm workig on an issue where my device running Linux with bluez is connected to a mobile phone over bluetooth. It also communicates to the phone over BLE with an android application. What I want is to disconnect the legacy connection while keeping the BLE connection active. I tried with **org.bluez.Device1** interface with method **DisconnectProfile(string uuid)**. Is there a way to get a list of registered UUIDs which I can use to disconnect the ones related to legacy connection while keeping the GATT profile active?

Comment: Which version of BlueZ are you using? If you are using a relatively late one then you can try disabling the BR/EDR part altogether by using "sudo btmgmt power off", "sudo btmgmt breder off", then "sudo btmgmt power on". After that you will only have BLE functionality on your Linux machine and any connection with only happen over BLE.

Comment: I'm using 5.49. It's device with audio driver so I need both BLE and BT. What I wanted is to find a way to get separate connect/disconnect events for legacy BT and BLE. Is there a way?